# Akka Stream - How to Stream from multiple SQS Sources

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

This is a subsequent post of [Akka Stream - Select Sink based on Element in Flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48758415/akka-stream-select-sink-based-on-element-in-flow).

Assume I have multiple SQS queues I'd like to stream from. I'm using the [AWS SQS Connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/sqs.html) of Alpakka to create `Source`.

```
implicit val sqsClient: AmazonSQSAsync = ???
val queueUrls: List[String] = ???
val sources: List[Source[Message, NotUsed]] = queueUrls.map(url => SqsSource(url))
```

Now, I'd like to `combine` the sources to merge them. However, the [Source.combine](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html) method doesn't support passing a list as parameter, but only support varargs.

```
def combine[T, U](first: Source[T, _], second: Source[T, _], rest: Source[T, _]*)(strategy: Int ⇒ Graph[UniformFanInShape[T, U], NotUsed])
```

Of course, I can finger type all sources parameters. But, the parameter will get pretty long if I have 10 source queues.

Is there a way to combine sources from a list of sources?

[Supplement]

As [Ramon J Romero y Vigil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1876739/ramon-j-romero-y-vigil) pointed out, it's a better practice to keep stream "a thin veneer". In this particular case, however, I use single `sqsClient` for all the `SqsSource` initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `foldLeft` to concatenate or merge the sources:

```
val sources: List[Source[Message, NotUsed]] = ???

val concatenated: Source[Message, NotUsed] = sources.foldLeft(Source.empty[Message])(_ ++ _)
// the same as sources.foldLeft(Source.empty[Message])(_ concat _)

val merged: Source[Message, NotUsed] = sources.foldLeft(Source.empty[Message])(_ merge _)
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Source.zipN`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5.9/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source$.html#zipN[T](sources:scala.collection.immutable.Seq[akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[T,_]]):akka.stream.scaladsl.Source[scala.collection.immutable.Seq[T],akka.NotUsed]) with `flatMapConcat`:

```
val combined: Source[Message, NotUsed] = Source.zipN(sources).flatMapConcat(Source.apply)
```

Comment: I tested both methods with two Sources, and they behaved differently. With `zipN` and `flatMapConcat`, it seems the source will round robin each source in the list of sources. The interesting discover is that if one of the source is `empty`, it never emits any element. In other words, `zipN` requires all sources have same number of elements to emit to the next flow.

Comment: The only change I would make is instead of concatenating we should merging. `sources.foldLeft(Source.empty[Message])(_ merge _)`